# Non recursive QuickSort

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm curious to know has my implementation of non recursive QuickSort algorithm some drawbacks or hidden rocks. What should be modified in order to optimize it? And what problems could happen when comparing two  objects in the way I do it?

```
public class QuickSort <T extends Number> {

private Integer first, last, boundLo, boundHi, pivot;
Integer temp[] = {0, 0};

public void sort(NewArrayList<T> vect) {
    Deque<Integer[]> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer[]>();

    first = 0;
    last = vect.size() - 1;
    stack.push(new Integer[] {first, last});

    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        sortStep(vect, stack);  
    }
}

private void sortStep(NewArrayList<T> vect, Deque<Integer[]> stack) {
    // initialize indices
    temp = stack.pop();
    first = temp[0];
    last = temp[1];

    boundLo = first;
    boundHi = last;
    pivot = last;

    while(first < last) {
        if(vect.get(first).doubleValue() >= vect.get(pivot).doubleValue()) {
            last--;
            if(first != last) 
                vect.swap(first, last);         
            vect.swap(last, pivot);
            pivot--;
        }
        else first++;
    }

    if(boundLo < (pivot - 1)) 
        stack.add(new Integer[] {boundLo, pivot - 1});

    if(boundHi > (pivot + 1)) 
        stack.add(new Integer[] {pivot + 1, boundHi});

}

}
```

And is ArrayList the best collection for this kind of sort?

```
public class  NewArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

public NewArrayList() {
    super();
}

public void swap(int index1, int index2) {
    this.set(index1, this.set(index2, this.get(index1)));
} 
}
```

The code after modifying in consideration of the suggestions

```
public class QuickSort <T extends Number> {

private int first, last, boundLo, boundHi, pivot;
int temp[] = {0, 0};

public QuickSort() {
    super();
}

public void sort(List<T> list) {

    Deque<int[]> stack = new ArrayDeque<int[]>();

    first = 0;
    last = list.size() - 1;

    stack.push(new int[] {first, last});

    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        sortStep(list, stack);  
    }
}

private void sortStep(List<T> list, Deque<int[]> stack) {

    temp = stack.pop();
    first = temp[0];
    last = temp[1];

    boundLo = first;
    boundHi = last;
    pivot = last;

    while(first < last) {
        if(list.get(first).doubleValue() >= list.get(pivot).doubleValue()) {
            last--;
            if(first != last) 
                Collections.swap(list, first, last);            
            Collections.swap(list, last, pivot);
            pivot--;
        }
        else first++;
    }

    if(boundLo < (pivot - 1)) 
        stack.add(new int[] {boundLo, pivot - 1});

    if(boundHi > (pivot + 1)) 
        stack.add(new int[] {pivot + 1, boundHi});
}

}
```

Comment: This is a good question, but it doesn't belong on SO.  Try posting your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don’t create a subclass of ArrayList just for adding a `swap` method. There is already `Collections.swap` which works for all lists. A good algorithm should work on the interface (in this case `List`) and not depend on a particular implementation.

Comment: And don’t use `Integer[]` where `int[]` can do the same.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Sort {   
    /** Returns a sorted list of attributes. */
    protected int[] sortAttributes1(int[] array) {

        Queue<Range> queue = new ArrayDeque<Range>();

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Range range = queue.poll();
            if (range.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            int left = range.getLeft();
            int right = range.getRight();
            // partition the range
            right = partition(array, left, right);
            Range lr = new Range(range.getLeft(), right - 1);
            Range rr = new Range(right + 1, range.getRight());

            queue.add(lr);
            queue.add(rr);
        }
        return array;
    }


    private int partition(int[] array, int left, int right) {
        int pivot = right - left >>> 2;


        while (left <= right) {
            int pivotVal = array[pivot];
            if (array[left] <= pivotVal) {
                left++;
                continue;
            }
            right--;
            if (left == right)continue;
            int temp = array[left];
            array[left] = array[right];
            array[right] = temp;
        }

        int temp = array[pivot];
        array[pivot] = array[right];
        array[right] = temp;

        return right;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Usually when people ask for feedback, they don't just want someone to create a completely new solution from scratch.