# Creating quicksort without recursion and stack

Tags: java, quicksort

I have a task to write quicksort (on only posivite numbers) algorythm in Java (I can't use any imports but Scanner) but without recursion and without stack.
I have two question about it :

1. I do understeand iterative quicksort with stack and recursive version but i cannot imagine how to do it without it. 
   I have heard about some 'in place' implementation but i dont really get it - is it solution for my problem?
   I would appreciate if anyone could show me a way to do it ( dont post implementation if you can, I just want to understeand it not copy someone's code) or recommend some book where I can find it ( or some similar problem ).
2. Is implementing sort by insertion for some small arrays a good idea? If so how big should be N in this code :

   ```
   if (arraySize < N)
       insertionSort
   else 
       quickSort
   fi
   ```

Comment: To answer the last question, about 15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently my task was to find **only** posivite numbers, here is my solution:

```
public static void quickSort(final int size) {
    int l = 0;
    int r = size - 1;
    int q, i = 0;
    int tmpr = r;
    while (true) {
        i--;
        while (l < tmpr) {
            q = partition(l, tmpr);
            arr[tmpr] = -arr[tmpr];
            tmpr = q - 1;
            ++i;
        }
        if (i < 0)
            break;
        l++;
        tmpr = findNextR(l, size);
        arr[tmpr] = -arr[tmpr];
    }
}

private static int findNextR(final int l, final int size) {
    for (int i = l; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < 0)
            return i;
    }
    return size - 1;
}

private static int partition(int l, int r) {
    long pivot = arr[(l + r) / 2];
    while (l <= r) {
        while (arr[r] > pivot)
            r--;
        while (arr[l] < pivot)
            l++;
        if (l <= r) {
            long tmp = arr[r];
            arr[r] = arr[l];
            arr[l] = tmp;
            l++;
            r--;
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

My array to sort is an static array in my class.
It is based on finding and creating negative numbers.
Partition is created by using middle element in array but using median is also good (it depends on array).
I hope someone will find this usefull.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a reference the Java8 implementation of Arrays.sort(int[]) uses a threshold of 47, anything less than that is sorted using insertion. Their quick sort implementation is however very complex with some initial overhead, so look upon 47 as an upper limit.

Answer (score -2):

A Google of "non-recursive quicksort" produced a slew of answers ... including this one:  [Non recursive QuickSort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124752/non-recursive-quicksort)  "Your language may vary," but the basic principle won't.

I personally think that, if you're going to sort something, you might as well use Quicksort in all cases . . .

Unless, of course, you can simply use a `sort()` function in your favorite target-language and leave it to the language implementors to have chosen a clever algorithm *(uhhhh, it's probably Quicksort...)* for you.  If you don't *have* to specify an algorithm to do such a common task, "don't!"  :-)

Comment: Yes google is very usefull but I couldn't find any non recursive quicksort with stack ( as stated in question).
I created this algorithm because it was my task to CREATE it not use some built-in function but thank you for your answer.

Comment: I've never *seen* a QuickSort implementation that was not recursive.  But ... "expressing a recursive algorithm in a non-recursive way is not *that* difficult ..."