# Early min on quicksort in java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem I can't -quite- wrap my head around. I'm racing quicksort vs heapsort on one million integers. Each of the sorting algorithms divides the list into 32 threaded sub-sections and then sorts those, finally merging each sorted subsection back into a coherent whole (using more threads).

Rather than sorting the whole sub-array using quicksort and then pushing the whole thing out to the mergers, I'm trying to find a way to find the min value(s) using quicksort and push that before the whole section has been sorted. Since I don't actually have enough cores to concurrently run all my threads I expect the performance impact to be negligible, but I'd like to test that theory.

Time on my machine with 4 cores is about 14 seconds plus or minus two for both heapsort and quicksort. Speed seems to depend on which algorithm I run first, even though I'm shuffling after the sort.

Here's my quicksort code right now:

```
//code borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124752/non-
//recursive-quicksort
 public synchronized void qSort(PipedOutputStream pout, int start, int sz) {

    Deque<int[]> stack = new ArrayDeque<int[]>();

    int first = start;
    int last = start + sz - 1;
    if(first >= arr.length || last >= arr.length){
        System.out.printf("\nSorting error: parameters out of bounds! Start %d, end %d \n", start, last);
        return;
    }
    stack.push(new int[] {first, last});
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        qsortStep(arr, stack);  
    }
     try { out = new ObjectOutputStream ( pout ); }
    catch (IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    while ( size >= 1 ) {
    try {
        // System.out.printf("sort is writing %d to pipe.\n",  v );
        out.writeObject( arr[start] );
        out.flush( );
                start++; size--;
            } catch(IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
}

private synchronized void qsortStep(T[] list, Deque<int[]> stack) {
    if(stack.isEmpty())
        return;
    int temp[] = stack.pop();
    int first = temp[0];
    int last = temp[1];

    int boundLo = first;
    int boundHi = last;


    //Pivot can be optimized to median of quintiles to mitigate O(n^2) on sorted arrays.
    int pivot = last;
    /*int sz = last - first;
    int pivots[] = {first, first+sz/5, first+2*sz/5, first+4*sz/5, last};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for(int j = 4; j > i; j--)
            if(arr[pivots[i]].compareTo(arr[pivots[j]]) > 0)
                swap(pivots, i, j);*/
    pivot = last;

    while(first < last) {
        //possible opportunity here for early min
        if(list[first].compareTo(list[pivot]) >= 0) {
            last--;
            if(first != last) 
                swap(list, first, last);            
            swap(list, last, pivot);
            pivot--;
        }
        else first++;
    }

    if(boundLo < (pivot - 1)) 
        stack.add(new int[] {boundLo, pivot - 1});

    if(boundHi > (pivot + 1)) 
        stack.add(new int[] {pivot + 1, boundHi});
}
```

Comment: If you really want to, it should be trivial to keep track of the minimum as you loop through the array, swap that with one of the outermost elements (which you then exclude from further sorting) and notify another thread of the position of that element. The overhead you'll be adding to quicksort will probably outweigh any benefit you can get from this, but I could be wrong.

Comment: As long as this thread and the other sorter paired with the next merger up both output their arrays in ascending order, the merger will pass it up the chain correctly without having to do another sort on the data. If I was sorting ints or Integers I could keep track of the min value like you were suggesting, can I do that with a template (comparable) type in Java?

Comment: Yes, you can keep track of the minimum by comparing elements in the same way you're currently comparing elements to the pivot (you probably want to store the index of the minimum rather than the minimum because you need the index to swap it).

Comment: @Dukeling yes but won't that cause Quicksort to degrade to O(n^2) since we are deliberately picking the smallest element(s) as the pivot? In every recursive case there will be one element (the pivot) on the left and every other element on the right.

Would we be able to simply follow the left-hand side of the stack down and say that when we only have one element in our list, that is both sorted and the smallest element, and then send that out through our queue and remove it from the list?

Comment: I just meant you can use roughly the same technique to compare elements as you did with the pivot. So you'll need to keep track of both the minimum and the pivot.

Comment: (A million items looks meagre for multi-threading, and q-sorting downto size 1 ambitious.) I'd try [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) as an alternative to streams. (I'd avoid establishing a `try`-block in a loop. Just `try-catch` in the outermost level in each thread, and declare *throws* below as needed.) Pushing `[ lo, hi ]` instead of just two `int`s looks over-engineered (and specify a size for the `new ArrayDeque()` that makes resizing improbable). Try "outputting `boundLo` and `pivot`" when not needing to sort that range.

Comment: A 4-core machine can hardly be old enough to need *seconds* to *heapsort* one million `int`s: what *are* you doing? (`PipedOut/InputStream`?)

Comment: I did try blockingQueue as an alternative to streams at one point, and my quicksort did run in two seconds instead of 14, and then I got pushback saying someone else wanted me to do it their way instead. So I'm using pipedIO and it's six times slower.

Comment: Restricted to `IOStream`, at least avoid to `flush()` every item. If and when sorting is no longer dwarfed by communication, consider asking this over at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).